# org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener does not take parameter

Tags: java, zk

I need to declare

```
private final EventListener<Event> eventListener;
```

but the following error occurred

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener does not take parameter.
```

in article this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/advanced-zk-asynchronous-ui use it. How can use this command?

Comment: i need use this cod:private final EventListener<Event> eventListener;

Comment: ZK5 still support java 1.4 so no generic in ZK 5.x.x, ZK6 moved to java 1.6, ZK 6.x.x use generic heavily.

Answer (score 5):

That's probably because you're not using the same version of ZK as the author of the article.

Here's the [javadoc for version 5.0.12](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/5.0.12/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/EventListener.html) (which doesn't take any generic parameter), and here's the [javadoc for the latest version](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/EventListener.html), which takes a generic parameter.